# Configure Apache to serve proper certificate chain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I am running Apache 2.2.15 on Red Hat 6.3, and I can't get certificate chains to work properly.

I am using my organisations PKI for certificate signing etc, which does not publish their root certificate to the internet.

So, I am using the directives `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile`, and `SSLCertificateChainFile`

I created my 2048 bit RSA key using openssl genrsa, and then used openssl to create a request from this key, and signed it using our Windows 2008 R2 CA.

I point to this signed certificate file with SSLCertificateFile.

The problem I have is with the chain file.

I have the root, intermediate and server certificates in PEM format, and have tried various combinations of these (concatenating the text files) to create the chain file e.g.

```
root
inter
server

server
inter
root

inter
root

root
inter
```

None of these work

To test this, I am doing the following:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:443 -CAfile root.cer
```

And the error I am getting is Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

However, the weird thing is when I run the following on the server:

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -CAfile root.cer
```

it works fine, I get a '0' return code, and can see the certificate chain at the top of the output.

So what is going on?

Without the chain file in place, I get the padlock icon in a web browser, but I am required to use curl in a separate script to connect to it, and this won't work in secure mode if the chaining doesn't work properly.

Comment: Is the root certificate actually in the trust store?